# how to invoke a function from an object in python?

Tags: python, file, object

```
class Poc:

    var = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.fileName = "input.txt"

    def readFile(self):
        with open('input.txt','r+') as fr:
            for line in fr:
                print line
                #enter code here

def main():
    obj=Poc()
    obj.readFile()
```

I was trying to pass arguments to the function and trying to read from the file. I cannot see anything happening after executing the code. I'm totally new to python please help.

I was trying to read from a file using the object.. please do share if anyone has links to learn python i couldn't find a good one.

Comment: learn from the "learnpythonthehardway"

Comment: http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 2):

Your `main` function is never called. You could remove the function definition of `main` and just unindent

```
 obj = Poc()
 obj.readFile()
```

to module level. It is then executed every time that the module is called directly (using `python yourscript.py`) or when it's imported by another module.

If you don't want the latter behavior, you can wrap it in a `if __name__=="__main__":` condition, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do). For your simple case this should not be necessary though.